# Tizen: EDC image can't keep it's original size

Tags: tizen, tizen-native-app

I'm trying to display an image with EDC, but it always keep scaling.

I have defined the `images` section:

```
images {
   image: "icon.png" COMP;
}
```

And also the `part` section:

```
part {
  name: "elm.icon";
  type: IMAGE;
  scale: 0;
  description {
    image.normal: "icon.png";
    fixed: 1 1;
    max: SOURCE;
  }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Reference: https://www.enlightenment.org/_legacy_embed/edcref.html#sec_collections_group_parts_description

If I change `max: SOURCE` to `max: 117 117` (original size of image) it will work:

[image]

How can I do this without specifying the image's original size in EDC?

Of course, by their reference it should work with the `max: SOURCE` config, but it doesn't..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried some tests. `max: SOURCE` doesn't seem to work.
Unfortunately, there seems to be no way to use the original size of the image other than explicitly writing the image size.

I thought this was a issue in EFL and made a code contribution.
(https://phab.enlightenment.org/D12215)
Perhaps if I'm right, EFL will support `max:SOURCE` soon.

It will probably take some time to be applied to Tizen SDK.
I will make a request to modify relevant Docs(Tizen).
I look forward to using `max:SOURCE` in next Tizen version.

Thank you :)